# Sufficient condition for convergence of measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have $(\mu_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ and $\mu$ $\sigma$-finite measures on $(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))$, where $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is the Borel set, such that $\mu_n(\mathbb{R}^d)\leqslant 1$ and $\mu(\mathbb{R}^d)\leqslant 1$. Let $\mathcal{C}_0$ denote the set of real-valued functions over $\mathbb{R}^d$ with limit 0 *ad infinitum*.

If we suppose that $\mu_n(\mathbb{R}^d)\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{}\mu(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and that
$$\forall f\in\mathcal{C}_0\quad\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f\mathrm{d}\mu_n\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f\mathrm{d}\mu,$$
can we assure that
$$\sup_{A\in\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)}|\mu_n(A)-\mu(A)|\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{}0~?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: consider $\mu_n$ the Dirac measure at $x_n:=\left(1/n,0,\dots,0\right)$. We have $\mu_n\left(\mathbb R^d\right)=1$ and for each continuous function, $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f\mathrm{d}\mu_n\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f\mathrm{d}\mu,$ where $\mu$ is the Dirac measure at $(0,\dots,0)$. But we do not even have $\mu_n\left(A\right)\to \mu\left(A\right)$ for all Borel set $A$, for example if $A:=\left\{(0,\dots,0)\right\}$.

Comment: This answer to the question but i'll add that in fact you (ADG) doesn't specify in which way you have $\mu_n\to \mu$ and also if $\mu_n$ is only assued to be $\sigma$-finite then $f\in C^0$ is not necessarilly $\mu_n$-integrable.

Finally you might want to check for "continuity sets"

Comment: Are these conditions sufficient to still guarantee a form of measure convergence? I did not manage to figure out if they could, for example, imply strong measure convergence.

Comment: @Renart I meant that $\mu_n(\mathbb{R}^d)\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{}\mu(\mathbb{R}^d)$ in the sense of real sequence convergence in $\mathbb{R}$. Concerning the integrability, I forgot to mention the fact that $\mu_n(\mathbb{R}^d),\mu(\mathbb{R}^d)\leqslant 1$. I'll edit my question.